# Loading BitmapDrawable in Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

So i basically have method which converts one image with some shape and than makes Drawable from my bitmap. Now there was method load bitmap drawable (setImageDrawable) but its deprecated.

So code is like this:

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromName(String name, Activity activity) {
        int resourceId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", activity.getPackageName());

        if(resourceId == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Bitmap croppedIcon = cropImage(activity, resourceId);
            if(croppedIcon == null)
                return null;
            return new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), croppedIcon);
        }
    }
```

cropImage return bitmap image with some custom shape.

How should i now load this drawable, which is actually nowhere located only in memory (as its generated) to Fresco SimpleDraweeView. Is it somehow possible to have this as Uri resource?

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(UriUtil.LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME) // "res"
    .path(String.valueOf(resId))
    .build();

simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: But i dont have resId since i generate this bitmap and its not saved anywhere

Comment: can you temporary store it in storage? and you are  converting image in shape like this? : https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview